# Override a val in data class

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, properties, data-class

I got an error of java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB when I tried this bit of code and the app crashed exactly 1 time and now it doesn't crash again, I would like to find out if this would cause any problems in the future before committing to this code

Below are examples of the interface/data class used in this part

```
interface y{
    val image
}

data class x(val anotherImage): y{
    override val image
        get() = image ?: anotherImage
}
```

What I want here is to have the val image contain the URL of an image, sometimes the back-end returns it in image and other times in anotherImage and that's why I wrote that bit of code, the use of an interface here is for another problem irrelevant to this issue

Answer (score 5):

You are recursively accessing the property using the actual property's name in your custom getter. Kotlin provides the `field` identifier which should be used to reference the property's value in its accessors:

```
val image
    get() = field ?: anotherImage
```

Comment: i tried using the field identifier but that's when i get an error that says property must be initialized

Comment: @MahmoudOmara Well it's hard to guess what you are trying to achieve based on the out-of-context example, but I'm assuming you want to initialize the nullable `image` property somewhere later in the code. Maybe you should change the `val image` declaration to `var image` and then initialize the property  inside the `x` class with `null`: `override var image: ImageType?  = null`.